# batch script to find a specific directory name

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to write a batch file script that find a directory name called "Mdata" for example in a path `"C:\project"`
If "Mdata" not exist in that path continue to search inside every directory in that path till "Mdata" found. if it found I will do set of commands in that directory "Mdata".

I'm trying to use `"For /D"` command :

```
FOR /D %variable IN (set) DO command [command-parameters]
```

but I'm not pretty much understand it and how it works.
Please your help, Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
for  /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b /s /a:d "C:\project\" ^|findstr /e /i "\Mdata"') do (
  @echo "%%~a"
  @echo some command here
)
```

try this.

Comment: Thanks - It works but it shows me only the last directory location that found and I have more than one directory called "Mdata". @npocmaka

Comment: I'm a little confused with the `dir` command syntax. When used with the `/a` switch, the help syntax reads `[/a[[:]attributes]]`. Is the `:` (colon) character part of the command? In this case, what is the output of `dir /a:d "C:\project\"?

Comment: @MinhTran the `:` can be omited. It is used to separate the /a swith from the needed attributes.`dir /a:d "C:\project\"` will print all directories under `c:\project` directory without the subfolders.

Comment: Aha thanks. And lastly, does `^|findstr /e /i "\Mdata"` pipe all sub-directory names under `C:\projects` matching `Mdata` to the `/a:d` switch or is the parameter immediately to the right of the `C:\project` argument understood to be the target directory name to be searched by `dir`?